# Select IDs where none of the events have a specific value BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have FULLVISITORIDS in my table with  different visitids and eventCategory.

I want to select FullvisitorID where none of the eventCategory is "A" 
For Example:

Select * from my_table

```
FullVisitorid    Visitid   .... .....hits.event.eventCategory
    1              123                       A                       
                                             B                       
                                             E
    1              147                       D                       
                                             E                       
                                             E 
    2              555                       F
                                             G
                                             D
```

I only want 2 as my final output.

I have tried the following code but it does not seem to work

```
Select fullvisitorid from  `my_table` where fullvisitorid not in (select distinct fullvisitorid from 
`my_table`, unnest(hits) hits where hits.event.eventCategory = 'A' )
```

Thanks For your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query gets all users without an A in a nested hit record:

```
with all_visitors as (
-- Get a list of all FullVisitorid
  select distinct FullVisitorid from `project.dataset.my_table`
),
eventCategory_As as (
-- Get a list of all FullVistiroid with A eventCategory
  select distinct FullVistorid
  from `project.dataset.my_table`
  left join unnest(hits) h
  where h.event.eventCategory = 'A'
)
-- Left join to get FullVisitorid who don't have an A eventCategory
select
  a.FullVisitorid
from all_visitors a
left join eventCategory_As b on a.FullVistiorid = b.FullVisitorid
where b.FullVisitorid is null
```